# what is the difference between algebra and Lie algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am writting a simple repport on Lie algebras and I thought I could start just with a ''strandard'' simple definition of algebra to make an introduction for Lie algebra and then relate these 2 definitions somehow with one another.

Does anyone know how I can do it in a descriptive way?

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

Well, certainly a Lie algebra is not in general an algebra, since Lie brackets are not associative in general. The simplest relationship between associative algebras and Lie algebras is that given any algebra $A$ over a field $k$, defining $[x, y] = xy - yx$ for $x, y \in A$ turns $A$ into a Lie algebra.

But the traditional motivation for studying Lie algebras has less (directly) to do with associative algebras and more to do with [Lie groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group), although one can motivate the definition of a Lie algebra without formally introducing Lie groups by talking about derivations: I do so in [this blog post](http://qchu.wordpress.com/2011/02/26/the-quaternions-and-lie-algebras-i/). The perspective I take there is that Lie algebras are a natural way to talk about *infinitesimal* symmetry, just as groups are a natural way to talk about symmetry in the ordinary sense.

Comment: thank you;) this explanaition makes sense